# Casting a char * to a char * [] in C

Tags: c

I'm having a problem casting, so is there a way to cast a type of:

```
char *result;
```

to a type of

```
char *argv[100];
```

?

If so, how would I do this or is there a safe way to do this?

Comment: @user1547386 Please ignore these who treat everyone with disdain and contempt.  As a new programmer you deserve a fair and honest answer that explains new concepts to you.

Comment: Are you trying to create an `exec` call? It might be better to describe your problem with some context.

Comment: `char **args;char *string;.....args=(char**)string;` but wouldn't recommend it.  With some context there are some standard functions that could be recommended though.

Comment: Also, note that you can't cast to an array type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char * result` is a string

and

`char * argv[100]` is array of strings.

You cannot convert string into array of strings. However, you can create an array of strings where the first array value is result.

```
argv[0] = result;
```

Comment: Well, `result` is a pointer first and foremost. It *may* be the pointer to an element of a string, or it may not.

Comment: I have seen memory pools implemented in a similar way as the OP asked.  Using char buf[POOL_SIZE] and a struct with linked list of "substrings" and some other key component that I cannot recall, but it was immensely faster than malloc and free only actually free'd if the pool got below a threshhold otherwise it was just setting a pointer to NULL.  The early versions in git showed that they attempted to use a char** instead of linked lists but it was less than ideal and abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

`char *result` is a pointer to a `char` 
`char *argv[100]` is an array of `char *`, so really it's a `char **` (a pointer to pointers)

Keep this in mind: 
`int* arr[8];` // An array of int pointers.
`int (*arr)[8];` // A pointer to an array of integers

This being the case, this is probably not what you want to be doing. I suppose the next question is: What were you trying to do? Or why?

Answer (score 0):

First, a short explanation:

```
  char *result;
```

The variable `result` is a pointer and when set it will point to a single character. However, as you know, a single character can be the start of a string that ends with the null (\0) character.

In C, a good programmer can use the pointer `result` to index through a string.

However, the string's length is **NOT** known until the pointer reaches a null character.

It is possible to define a fixed length string of characters, in this case code:

```
 char s[100];
```

Now, the fun begins. `s` per Kernighan and Ritchie (K&R) is a pointer to a string of characters terminated with a 0.

So, you can code:

```
 s[0] = 'a';
 *s   = 'a';

 s[1] = 'b';
 *(s+1) = 'b';
```

These are equivalent statements.

As mentioned in other posts, let's add explicit parens to your argv statement:

```
char *(argv[100]);
```

Thus, this is an array of 100 pointers to characters (each of which might or might not be the start of a string of characters).

Comment: `s[1]` and `*s+1` are not equivalent. `s[1]` and `*(s+1)` are. `*s+1` would evaluate to `'b'` in your example and wouldn't compile.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to downvote you, but I can't see how the "arrays are pointers" lie could help people to understand how C works: he already has troubles with types and conversions, and the fact that arrays automatically become pointers to their first element when needed it's not a really difficult concept to grasp, isn't it? :)

Comment: I agree with @effeffe. s is not a pointer to any string. 's' acts a pointer to the first element of the array. It becomes more fun, when somebody tries to do &s, and expects it to be a pointer to pointer, where it actually points to the same location as 's'.

Comment: @effeffe, an array name can be treated as a pointer per K&R.  How a compiler implements an array is up to the compiler's coders.

Comment: @JackCColeman arrays are treated as a pointer *sometimes*, not always, and I think a C programmer must know when this happen and when not to understand how the language works. And this is not implementation-defined and it has nothing to do with implementations, this is not up to the compiler's coders (if the compiler is standard-compliant, obviously) but it's part of the standard which states precisely when the conversion takes place and when not. And these rules are pretty easy.

Comment: @effeffe, you will have to be more explicit about when an array name cannot be "symbolically" thought of as a pointer.

Comment: "simbolically"? When we have an array, we can always "think" about a pointer to its first element, this is pretty obvious but misleading. The compiler doesn't care about what we "think" and just follows the standard. If you tell a beginner "arrays are pointer, simple", they will expect `sizeof(int [10])` evaluating to the size of a pointer, but this won't happen, just as `&array` won't give a double pointer. That's why one should not treat arrays as pointers. And if you want me to be more explicit, the same happens for `_Alignof` and string literals in array initializations (C11-6.3.2.1/3).

Comment: @effeffe, I think K&R, 2nd Ed. does a good job of explaining how arrays and pointers are synonymous.

Comment: Well, I really like that book but... no, it doesn't, totally, IMHO it's confused and misleading about that point. Anyway, where does it states that they are synonymous? Also, I don't understand what we're talkin' about: they are *not* synonymous, they are not the same thing, they are not interchangeable, and one should not always think about an array identifier as a pointer to the first element, period. You can find a lot of discussions abut this, and c-faq has a great section about this: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: @effeffe, int a[10]; the third element can be found as: a[2] or a+2 where `a` is a pointer and +2 is an offset from the `a` pointer.  Anyway, whatever constructs help write clean, readable code is fine with me.

Comment: Sorry, but... what the hell has this to do with previous comments? Since the sum operator can't be applied to arrays, but it's fine with a pointer and an integer, `a` is converted to a pointer (*"arrays become pointers when needed"*). No one ever said something different. Access to elements it's not the only operation you can do with an array. Again, I really can't understand what your point is. I just said that they are different and we can't choose what to think,we just have to know language rules (and tell people the real rules).

Comment: @effeffe "a is converted to a pointer" here is where we part company.  `a` is always a pointer to an array, at least as an abstract idea, a compiler might implement `a` as not a pointer.  But, abstractly it is.

Comment: a is more than a pointer, because it has a beginning and an end, while a pointer is just a beginning (or an end, or something else, who knows?). And the astract idea is that an array is a contiguos list of elements while a pointer is the address of an object, for me. But hey - if you're happy thinking your way, ok. Just put int a[10]; in a file and extern int *a; in another one, and look how C thinks different from you. But if you know it, no problem. :)

Comment: @effeffe, I am doing that now, but I bet your example is why casting was invented!

Comment: @effeffe, you should know that a declaration and its extern should match?  Sorry, I didn't think of that prior to coding: `extern int a[10];`  and `printf("%d %d %d", *a, *(a+1), *(a+2));`.  Its been nice talking with you.  Goodbye.

Comment: It was to say that, while you can pass to a function an array where a pointer is expected, this is not always the correct point of view IMHO. My pleasure, goodbye!

Answer (score 0):

What does `result` contain, and what do you expect `argv` to contain after the conversion?

For example, if `result` points to a list of strings separated by a delimiter, like `"foo,bar,bletch,blurga,..`, and you want each string to be a separated element in `argv`, like

```
argv[0] == "foo"
argv[1] == "bar"
argv[2] == "bletch"
argv[4] == "blurga"
```

then you could not accomplish this with a simple cast; you'd have to actually scan `result` and assign individual pointers to `argv`.